# How to prove that $\int (1-x^2)^{k-1} \ dx= x \cdot {_2F_1}(\frac 12, 1-k, \frac 32, x^2)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I am reading a paper and there is written that

$$\int (1-x^2)^{k-1} \ dx = x \cdot  {_2F_1}\left(\frac 12, 1-k, \frac 32, x^2\right)$$

where $ {_2F_1}$ is the hypergeometric function

(this should hold for $x \in [-1, 1]$)

How is this result proven?

I tried computing the taylor expansion of $(1-x^2)^{k-1}$ is  neighborhood of $0$, then integrate term by term and find $a,b,c,z$ such that our geometric function has the same form. This may be doable but I find it hard to compute the $\displaystyle \frac{d^n}{x^n}\left(1-x^2\right)^{k-1}$

Are there easier ways? Thank you! :-)

Comment: And what is $F_1$?

Comment: Also $\cdot_2$ is not known to me.

Comment: edited! should be more clear now :-)

Comment: The left side is a constant, the rhs depends on $x$?

Comment: @Thomas It's indefinite integral, the lhs too depends on $x$ :)

Comment: The situation is still not clear to me. Is $x$ one of the endpoints of the integration interval? Did you try the substitution $x=cosϕ$?

Comment: @Urgje No it's just the indefinite integral of $x$. What is not clear in that? :) Substituting $x = \cos y$ would leave me with a difficult expression.. (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sin%5E%282a-1%29)

Comment: On the one hand you integrate over $x$ and on the other the integral depends on it. I assume it is a matter of notation.

Comment: @Urgje I do not integrate over $x$. Take for example $\int x$. it is $\int x = x^2 / 2$; it still depends on $x$

Comment: I did not know this notation. Usually one uses $F(x)$ for the primitive of $f(x)$

Comment: @Urgje It is a matter of notation then. I thought that it was universally accepted, but apparently it isn't so :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $X=x^2$ :
$$\int (1-x^2)^{k-1}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int (1-X)^{k-1}X^{-1/2}dX=\frac{1}{2}B_{X}(\frac{1}{2},k)$$
$B$ is the Incomplete Beta function.

The Incomplete Beta function is a particular hypergeometric function, with relationship :
$$ _2F_1(a,b;b+1;X)=bX^{-b}B_X(b,1-a)$$
In this case $a=1-k$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}$:
$$ _2F_1(1-k,\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}+1;X)=\frac{1}{2}X^{-\frac{1}{2}}B_{X}(\frac{1}{2},k)$$

$$ _2F_1(1-k,\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};x^2)=\frac{1}{2}x^{-1}B_{X}(\frac{1}{2},k)$$

$$\frac{1}{2}B_{X}(\frac{1}{2},k)=x \: _2F_1(1-k,\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};x^2)=x \: _2F_1(\frac{1}{2},1-k;\frac{3}{2};x^2)=\int (1-x^2)^{k-1}dx$$

Comment: awesome. Thank you! :-)