# How to prove that ${_2F_1}(1-k, 1, k+1, -1) = k\cdot {_2F_1}(\frac 12, 1-k, \frac 32, 1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

This is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495050/how-to-prove-that-int-1-x2k-1-x-2f-1-frac-12-1-k-frac-32-x2)

Since we know that $$\int (1-x^2)^{k-1} \ dx = x \cdot  {_2F_1}\left(\frac 12, 1-k, \frac 32, x^2\right)$$
(see linked question) then it's clear that

$$\int_0^1 (1-x^2)^{k-1} \ dx =  {_2F_1}\left(\frac 12, 1-k, \frac 32, 1\right)$$

If we use the relationship $$\int_0^1 x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-b-1}(1-zx)^{-a} \ dx  = B(b, c-b) \cdot {_2F_1}(a,b,c,z)$$

where $B$ is the beta function, we get that

$$\int_0^1 (1-x^2)^{k-1} \ dx  = \frac 1k \cdot {_2F_1}(1-k, 1, k+1, -1)$$

Which implies

$$ {_2F_1}(1-k, 1, k+1, -1) = k\cdot {_2F_1}\left(\frac 12, 1-k, \frac 32, 1\right)$$

Is there an easier way to prove this relationship? How could one see that this is correct without doing what is written before?

---

In general dealing with the hypergeometric function seems a mess. I tried using various (linear) transformation, but with no use. I can't use Kummer's theorem to simplify the LHS, and in general I have no idea how to manipulate the hypergeometric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to do it by showing
$$
{_2F_1}(1-k, 1, k+1, -1) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\;\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(k+\frac{1}{2})}
\\
{_2F_1}\left(\frac 12, 1-k, \frac 32, 1\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\;\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(k+\frac{1}{2})}
$$
or would that be the same proof?

See [$z=-1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Kummer.27s_theorem_.28z.C2.A0.3D.C2.A0.E2.88.921.29) and [$z=1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Special_values_at_z.C2.A0.3D.C2.A01)

Comment: +1 that is awesome! But how did you arrive at such relations? Is there a "guideline" or a technique to find such values? I did not find anything like that on wikipedia. No why would it be the same proof? I don't see the link :)

Comment: I had seen kummer 's theorem but how do you apply it since $c \neq 1 + a - b$?

Comment: $a=1,b=1-k,c=1+k$

Comment: Ah, I see, $c = 1+b-a$, which is okay since $a$ and $b$ are basically the same ( I mean you can swap them at will )

Comment: Good, it was just kummer's theorem.. Don't know why I did not see it before :) Thank you! :)