# What to do when finding "complex" result by accident?

Tags: soft-question, education

This happened a couple of times today. While working on some problems, you find unexpected relationship between objects, which are not obvious to find directly. For example today I found out that

$$\large\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x^2)^{k-1} \left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{-k} \left(\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{2k}-1\right)}{k \log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)} \ dx = 1 $$

(I did not double check it so it may be wrong. But that's just an example. Another one is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495056/how-to-prove-that-2f-11-k-1-k1-1-k-cdot-2f-1-frac-12-1-k-fra))

I don't really know what to do in this situations.. I mean I could just forget about it, but maybe it would lead into interesting generalizations? On the other hand these "generalizations" are tough to see because the result pops up almost "by chance" while doing unrelated calculations.

What do you do when something like this happens?

Comment: I couldn't get this integral to converge on $[0,1]$ regardless of the value of $k$.

Comment: @IanMiller That may very well be the case as I used fubini-tonelli and other theorems without worrying about their applicability. But again, this is only an example to show what I mean :-) I have edited in another example anyhow :)

Comment: The strong structure in the terms inside suggest that the expression derives from a simpler one, for which the result would probably be trivial (or at least, the interesting one).
Plenty of complex equations are just encoded simpler ones. Plenty of complex equalities exists, and they are rarely interesting. 
I understand you would like to "do something with them"  out of any context ?

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET Not really do something with them, rather understand what mathematicians do; is it always lost time or for example is better to keep them somewhere because typically they will result useful? Of course I don't expect a "hard" answer, rather something along the lines of "I usually to this because typically happens that." I'll be satisfied if the answer is "I usually thrown them away because they are typically useless, unless certain rare occasion"

Comment: Unfortunately I can hardly relate; I haven't ventured outside abstract algebra in a while. For your particular example it might be worth noting that the numerator of the integrand equals
$$(1-x^2)^{-1}((1-x)^{2k}-(1+x)^{2k}).$$